# executing jquery script only once first time when page loads

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following jquery script on  my web page. This script is ran when I load the page the very first time. I don't want this script to run again, only the first time when the page loads. Is it possible to do that? I googled it and someone mentioned that I can put .one and then it will be executed only once. Below is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //Scroll div you the bottom onpage load
        $("#divTest").scrollTop($("#divTest")[0].scrollHeight);
    });
```

My issue is I have a datagrid on this page that is inside the div tags. When I update the datagrid. The scroll bar of the datagrid goes all the way to the bottom. Although, I want, when I do the update on the datagrid, the row that has been updated the page should stay there. For this purpose, I have the following code on the page. User wants that when they are first redirected to this page that has datagrid on it, the scroll bar should be all the way to the bottom  and that is the reason, I have above jquery in it.

```
<div id="divTest" style="overflow:auto; height:900px; width:1600px" onscroll="SetDivPosition()" >
```

The javascript is like this

```
       function SetDivPosition() {
        var intY = document.getElementById("divTest").scrollTop;
        document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
    }
```

and this

```
     window.onload = function () {
        var strCook = document.cookie;
        if (strCook.indexOf("!~") != 0) {
            var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
            var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
            var strPos = strCook.substring(intS + 2, intE);
            document.getElementById("divTest").scrollTop = strPos;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code, as is, will only execute once whenever the page loads.  What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I edited my code above.

Comment: I agree with David. There's no need to complicate with cookies or any other mechanism of "remembering" whether that scroll-logic executed or not, as long as you keep it within document-ready (because it won't execute more then once, and it is guaranteed to execute, even if  you inject that code after document already loaded).

Comment: I don't know what that window-onload is doing; get rid of that. The flow should be close to this: right before you update the grid, capture window scroll position (I think it's `var before = $(window).scrollTop()`). Then, update the grid. Finally, restore the window position (`$(window).scrollTop(before);`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if($.cookie("scriptExecuted")!="yes") {
        //Scroll div you the bottom onpage load
        $("#divTest").scrollTop($("#divTest")[0].scrollHeight);
        $.cookie("scriptExecuted", "yes");
}
});
```

Use of cookies would be helpful, you can use this lovely jquery plugin to set, unset and retrieve cookie values. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Logic is simple, check for the set cookie, if not set execute, and when executed, set the cookie.

CDN for jQuery-Cookies https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js

here goes the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kzLkg1rk/

Comment: I am getting an error at this line saying JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'cookie'  if ($.cookie("scriptExecuted") != "yes") {  I am using jquery 1.9.1.js

Comment: Did you use cookie plugin?

Comment: No, I didn't. Should I just do Install-Package jquery.cookie -Version 1.0.0 . I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: Yup sure, just call the cookie plugin CDN, as you call for jquery, and just below jquery..

Answer (score 0):

When you say once do you mean once per page load or once in all?

If it is once per page load then I am positive that your code will work. If no event is called then this should happen only once.If it keeps happening check how many times you are loading the script.

If you mean you don't want it to run anymore but the one time a browser loads it then you need a cookie.